# VueJs: Difference Between importing it into the HTML and creating an Backend API and having VUE interact with it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Could someone explain to me what is the difference between importing VUE in the script tag like below...
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>`
and creating a vue project using the CLI which will connect to the back-end.

1. Will there be a difference in the production of my Web App or will it be identical?
2. When will it be recommended for me to use either option?

Comment: Please edit your question and don't make people try to dig in the link for one line of code, instead clearly show what is the alternative you take into account for `<script src="..">` thing.

Comment: @vahdet I have just edited the question. Is something like this better?

Comment: Well, personally I am still not clear about what exactly you compare. I hate doing this, but maybe you can take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using vue-cli you open yourself to many new possibilities - like using webpack to build your application, npm to manage dependencies, and most importantly - [Single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html).

**Hello.vue** (example single file component)

```
<template>
  <p>{{ greeting }} World!</p>
</template>

<script>
import LibraryName from 'library-name' // <- thats how you can import dependencies

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      greeting: "Hello"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    exampleMethod () {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
p {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```